# Ruby way to Check for string palindrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3

How to check if a string is palindrome or not using ruby code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
def check_palindromic(variable)
  if variable.reverse == variable #Check if string same when reversed 
    puts "#{ variable } is a palindrome."
  else # If string is not the same when reversed
    puts "#{ variable } is not a palindrome."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 52):

If you are not acquainted with Ruby's `String` methods, you should have a look at the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html), it's very good. Mithun's answer already showed you the basic principle, but since you are new to Ruby, there's a couple more things to keep in mind:

*) If you have a predicate method, it's customary to name it with a trailing question mark, e.g. `palindrome?`.

*) Boolean expressions evaluate to a boolean, so you don't need to explicitly return `true` or `false`. Hence a short idiomatic version would be

```
def palindrome?(str)
  str == str.reverse
end
```

*) Since Ruby's classes are open, you could add this to the string class:

```
class String
  def palindrome?
    self == self.reverse
  end
end
```

*) If you don't want to monkey-patch `String`, you can directly define the method on single object (or use a module and [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-extend)):

```
foo = "racecar"
def foo.palindrome?
  self == self.reverse
end
```

*) You might want to make the palindrome check a bit more complex, e.g. when it comes to case or whitespace, so you are also able to detect palindromic sentences, capitalized words like "Racecar" etc.

```
pal = "Never a foot too far, even."
class String
  def palindrome?
    letters = self.downcase.scan(/\w/)
    letters == letters.reverse
  end
end
pal.palindrome? #=> true
```

Comment: The uses of `self.` (but not the uses of `self` without the dot) are unnecessary.

Comment: So are parenthesis around method arguments. Coding style is like taste, everyone else's is bad ;-)

Comment: Isn't this super expensive? Creating a new array just to check if the word is palindrome? I know it is short code and looks pretty... but it feels expensive...

Comment: The only version that creates an array is the last one, which actually in the process removes punctuation, ignores case etc. But if you're really into micro-optimizing short code snippets on SO knock yourself out.

Answer (score 12):

The recursive solution shows how strings can be indexed in Ruby:

```
def palindrome?(string)
  if string.length == 1 || string.length == 0
    true
  else
    if string[0] == string[-1]
      palindrome?(string[1..-2])
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

If reading the Ruby string documentation is too boring for you, try playing around with the Ruby practice questions on [CodeQuizzes](http://www.codequizzes.com/) and you will pick up most of the important methods.

Comment: it's genius! Linear time complexity

Answer (score 5):

```
def is_palindrome(value)
 value.downcase!

 # Reverse the string
 reversed = ""
 count = value.length

 while count > 0
  count -= 1
  reversed += value[count]
 end
# Instead of writing codes for reverse string
# we can also use reverse ruby method
# something like this value == value.reverse  
if value == reversed
  return "#{value} is a palindrom"
 else
  return "#{value} is not a palindrom"
 end
end

puts "Enter a Word"
a = gets.chomp
p is_palindrome(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class String
  def palindrome?
    self.downcase == self.reverse.downcase
  end
end

puts "racecar".palindrome? # true
puts "Racecar".palindrome? # true 
puts "mississippi".palindrome? # false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str= gets.chomp 
str_rev=""
n=1
while str.length >=n
    str_rev+=str[-n]
    n+=1
end

if str_rev==str
    puts "YES"
else
    puts "NO"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
> first method
a= "malayalam"
  if a == a.reverse
    puts "a is true"
  else
    puts "false"
  end

> second one
a= "malayalam"
a=a.split("")
i=0
ans=[]
  a.count.times do
    i=i+1
      k=a[-(i)]
      ans << k
    end
  if a== ans
      puts "true"
  else
      puts "false"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def palindrome?(string)
  string[0] == string[-1] && (string.length <= 2 || palindrome?(string[1..-2]))
end
```

Comment: Please include a brief explanation of the code and how it solves the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Time complexity = O(n), Space complexity = O(n)

This solution does not use the reverse method of the String class. It uses a stack(we could use an array that only allows entry and exit of elements from one end to mimic a stack).

```
def is_palindrome(str)
  stack = []
  reversed_str = ''
  str.each_char do |char|
    stack << char
  end
  
until stack.empty?
  reversed_str += stack.pop 
end

if reversed_str == str
  return true
 else
  return false
end
end
```

Solution 2:  Time complexity = O(n), Space complexity = O(1)

```
 def inplace_reversal!(str)
   i =0
   j = str.length - 1
   while i < j
    temp = str[i]
    str[i] = str[j]
    str[j] = temp
    i+=1
    j-=1
   end
    return str
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def palindrome?(str)
    return "Please pass the string" if str.nil?
    str = str.downcase
    str_array = str.split('')
    reverse_string = str_array.each_index{ |index| str_array[str_array.count - index - 1 ] end
    return ("String #{str} is not a palindrome") unless str == reverse_string.join('')

    "String #{str} is palindrome"
end
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important, take a look at this:

```
def palindrom? word
    (word.length/2).times do |index|
        if (word[index]!=word[word.length-index-1])
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```