# What's Wrong With my Palindrome Program? (Ruby, user inputs the string themselves)

Tags: ruby, palindrome

I so decided to make a palindrome program, but I did so by checking a string inputted by a user. In order to do this properly, I wanted to strip away the capitalization, spaces, and punctuation. I managed to get everything but the punctuation part of it working. Every time I try with a string like "Madam, I'm Adam" the program crashes. I am very new to Ruby, and I have only learned my knowledge through the Codecademy website. And I also using the editor provided to run my code. Every time I run it like:

```
puts "Enter a string!" 
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!
user_input = user_input.gsub(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, '')
if user_input.include?(" ")
  user_input.gsub!(/ /, "")
end
if user_input == user_input.reverse
  print "Is a pallindrome"
else
  print "Is not a pallindrome"
end
```

It crashes. But if I run it like:

```
puts "Enter a string!" 
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!
if user_input.include?(" ")
  user_input.gsub!(/ /, "")
end
if user_input == user_input.reverse
  print "Is a pallindrome"
else
  print "Is not a pallindrome"
end
```

It works. What a I doing wrong here? Why does my program always crash when I attempt to take away the punctuation?

Comment: What exception does it crash with?

Comment: ...and what string have you entered and on what line does the exception occur?

Comment: Here are some other ways to check for palindromes with Ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462512/ruby-way-to-check-for-string-palindrome

Comment: It tells me that my program has "Taken too long to run" and then asks me if I want to stop it, or try to let it continue. And, I tried using the string "Madam, I'm Adam" because the person who's going to be testing this program will most likely use that string. It crashes with any punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is wrong with your program. Codecademy has a bug reading any input that has a quote in it...

Try it out:

```
gets
```

Just enter `'` to see it crash...

My advice is to get your own local environment to develop on ruby. There are many many resources out there to help you install a simple ruby environment on any OS.

After that, download and install **Sublime Text** and start creating your ruby source file. Then you will see that `ruby <your_file>.rb` will work perfectly as you expect.