# Ruby palindrome boolean returning false

Tags: ruby

Why does this return `false`?

```
def palindrome?(word)
  if word == word.reverse!
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

puts palindrome?("Stats")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby way to Check for string palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462512/ruby-way-to-check-for-string-palindrome)

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. It returns `true`.

Comment: brykka, if you mean you expected `palindrome?('Stats')` to return `false` but it returns `true`, you should (edit to) say that. I expect confusion about that was the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it was returning false when I expected it to return true. I'm sorry about the confusion. Thank you for your help, I'm extremely new to both this website and Ruby.

Comment: Not a problem. Note that, while `"stats" == "stats".reverse #=> true`, `"Stats" == "Stats".reverse #=> false`, so if  you regard `"Stats"` to be a palindrome the test should be `s = "Stats".downcase; s == s.reverse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. At first, you shouldn't use `reverse!`. This method modifies `word`, but you only need to get the modified result. So you should use `reverse` instead.
2. Your method can be simplified to:

   ```
   def palindrome?(word)
       word == word.reverse
   end
   ```
3. `"Stats"` is not a palindrome unless you convert it to lower or upper register:

   ```
   def palindrome?(word)
       word = word.downcase
       word == word.reverse
   end
   ```

The result of testing the final version is:

```
puts palindrome?("Stats")
# => true
```

Comment: Just to be safe, you should use `word = word.downcase` instead of `word.downcase!`, in order to not surprise the caller. Consider the case `word = "Stats"; print "#{word} is #{palindrome?(word) ? "" : "not "}a palindrome!"` -  prints "stats is a palindrome" - with lowercase "stats"!

Comment: You are not answering the OP's question.

Comment: Provided work-around, not a answer to question _why?_

Comment: @Amadan, thank you for your suggestion! I've edited my post.

Comment: @sawa, Before your edition, OP's question was 'Why is this returning false?' As I understand it, he used word 'false' to mean "wrong result", not a FalseClass object. So I explained what the error was, and judging by the fact that the OP accepted my answer, that's exactly what he wanted to know.

Comment: @ray, my answer about difference between `reverse` and `reverse!` is answer *why* method returned wrong value.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Under that interpretation of the question, the OP has even not stated what a "wrong result" is, or what the "right result" is. And it would be impossible to answer the question.

Comment: @sawa, "Wrong result" for a method whose task is to check whether an argument is a palindrome is a result that gives an incorrect estimate of whether the argument is a palindrome. For example, if it always returns true, even if the argument is not a palindrome.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky If you are mentioning that, then the question is: "Why does the method return `true` irrespective of the argument?" And I don't see your answer to that question. Cary Swoveland has given the correct answer to that question.

Comment: @sawa, If I had the rights to directly edit a question, I would change it to "Why does the method return `true` irrespective of the argument and how to fix it?". I think this is exactly the question that the OP would like to get an answer to. And I tried to give this answer. But @CarySwoveland's answer is a very good too.

Comment: @sawa and Ivan, I don't want to get involved in this discussion except to make a point I think we can all agree on (Ivan included, upon reflection): one can conclude absolutely nothing from the fact that an OP selects a particular answer.

Answer (score 4):

If `str` is any string,

```
str == str.reverse!
  #=> true
```

For example,

```
str = "abc"
str == str.reverse!
  #=> true
```

`str == str.reverse!` is syntactic sugar for `str.==(str.reverse!)`. Ruby's first step in evaluating this expression is to evaluate the argument, `str.reverse!`. That expression does two things: it replaces the value of `str` with the reversed string and it returns the reversed string. The method `==` then compares the value returned by `str.reverse!` with the value held by `str`. As they are the same, the expression returns `true`.

Comment: Actually, the OP is asking why his method returns `false`, whereas you are saying it cannot return anything other than `true`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Actually, the OP's claim cannot be reproduced. The OP's code returns `true`.

Comment: @Cary Great answer. You might want to add why the evaluation happens in that order, i.e., that `==` is a method, so its argument  is evaluated before the method is executed.

Comment: It does only answer exact _why?_ . String is mutated before it gets compared

Comment: @JörgWMittag, In the original question, the word 'false' was not designated as `false` (look at question's edit history). Most likely, the author just meant the 'wrong result', not a `FalseClass` object.